Python dataframe: dynamic dataframe and column names
I have the following source data frame:
data = {
    "Category": ["A","A","B","C","C"],
    "Value": [16,10,8,8.3,17]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

What I'd like to get is the separate dataframe for each unique value of Category variable, i.e df_A, df_B, df_C etc.
Each dataframe should contain only related rows i.e df_A contains all rows from source df where Category=="A" etc.
Also I need to rename the Value column, i.e. in df_A column Value should be renamed to ValueA, df_B -> ValueC, etc.
I wrote the following code:
for name in df['Category'].unique():
    df_name = "df_" + name
    col_name = "Value" + name
    exec(f'{df_name} = df[df["Category"] == name]')
    exec(f'{df_name}.reset_index(inplace=True)')
    exec(f'{df_name}.rename(columns={{"Value" : {col_name} }}, axis=1, inplace=True)')

The data frame with the dynamic name is created but have a problem with the last line where rename is used
I'm getting an error:
NameError: name 'ValueA' is not defined

It seems {col_name} should be somehow quoted? I tried number of options but failed :(
Could You help me how to solve the column rename problem, please?


Typo: {col_name} should be "{col_name}". Also, use either columns or axis on rename, not both.

To avoid a SettingWithCopyWarning you should use exec(f'{df_name} = {df_name}.rename(columns={{"Value" : "{col_name}" }})'). That said, creating variable names in this way is best avoided. It is difficult to understand how you will later access the newly created DFs and how this is useful.

Thank You for your feedback, I don't how how I didn't try with a simple quotation ;)

Dynamically adding names to a Python namespace is generally considered a bad idea: see e.g. here, and here. Using exec is also best avoided: see e.g. here, and here.
Here, as often, it's better to create a dictionary.

You can use df.groupby to split your categories and work with the name (k = key) and data (v = value) for each group within a dictionary comprehension.
d = {f'df_{k}': v.reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'Value': f'Value{k}'}) 
     for k, v in df.groupby("Category")}

Output:
{'df_A':   Category  ValueA
 0        A    16.0
 1        A    10.0,
 'df_B':   Category  ValueB
 0        B     8.0,
 'df_C':   Category  ValueC
 0        C     8.3
 1        C    17.0}

Access a particular df:
d['df_C']

  Category  ValueC
0        C     8.3
1        C    17.0

